# Adding a tile to the Windows 10 Action Center

Tags: c++, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I am using C++ and the Windows Framework. Is there a way to add my own custom tile to the Windows 10 Action Center, like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there is no way to add a "Quick Action" button. You can try adding a request (or upvote an existing item) on the [Windows Dev Uservoice site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).